# JavaFX GridPane - Configuring controls to grow and occupy all the available space

Tags: java, layout, javafx-8, gridpane

Trying to achieve:

1. `Text Field 1` and `Text Field 3` should occupy all the available free space
2. `Button 1` and `Button 2` should have same width

Issue:

`Text Field 1` and `Text Field 3` are NOT occupying all the available free space (though they are growing once `Label` is completely displayed)

Here is the screen shot:

[image: GridPane - Controls are not occupying all the available space]

```
// Removed imports for brevity

public class GridPaneTest extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    primaryStage.setTitle("GridPane Test");

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    // gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    gridPane.setHgap(5);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));

    TextField tf1 = new TextField("Text Field 1");
    GridPane.setHgrow(tf1, Priority.ALWAYS);
    gridPane.add(tf1, 0, 0);
    TextField tf2 = new TextField("Text Field 2");
    GridPane.setHgrow(tf2, Priority.NEVER);
    gridPane.add(tf2, 1, 0);
    Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
    button1.setMaxWidth(140);
    GridPane.setHgrow(button1, Priority.NEVER);
    GridPane.setHalignment(button1, HPos.RIGHT);
    gridPane.add(button1, 2, 0);

    TextField tf3 = new TextField("Text Field 3");
    GridPane.setHgrow(tf3, Priority.ALWAYS);
    gridPane.add(tf3, 0, 1, 2, 1);
    Button button2 = new Button("Button 2 Button 2");
    button2.setMaxWidth(140);
    GridPane.setHgrow(button2, Priority.NEVER);
    GridPane.setHalignment(button2, HPos.RIGHT);
    gridPane.add(button2, 2, 1);

    Label label1 = new Label(
        "Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1 Label 1");
    GridPane.setHgrow(label1, Priority.ALWAYS);
    gridPane.add(label1, 0, 2, 3, 1);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane)); 

    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [GridPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

> if an application needs to explicitly control the size of rows or columns, it may do so by adding RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints objects to specify those metrics

```
gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
  .addAll(new ColumnConstraints(), new ColumnConstraints(),
    new ColumnConstraints(140) /* Control the third column size */);
```

Screen shot:

[image: GridPane - Demo configuring controls to grow and occupy all the available free space]

Comment: Now Button width can be set to `Button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE)` - for the two buttons to be of same size.